# Spring boot + H2 Db into File + /h2-console

Tags: java, spring, maven, h2, flyway

I'm working on a project where I need to migrate database and use H2 database on a file for development environment.

I added the flyway dependendy into pom of my Spring Boot (1.4.0.RELEASE) web application:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
        <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Then I configured db and flyway on application.properties:

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2-console
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:./db/pippo.db;
spring.datasource.username=pippo
spring.datasource.password=pluto


flyway.enabled=true
flyway.url=jdbc:h2:file:./db/pippo.db
flyway.user=pippo
flyway.password=pluto
flyway.locations=classpath:db/migration
```

Then if I launch the application it properly creates the database file into ./db/pippo.db... and so I suppose that all will work fine, but when I write http://localhost:8081/h2-console on my browser I receive 404 response.
What's wrong with my configuration?

Thank you all

Comment: Are you sure that your server runs on port 8081? Also, what logging output do you get? In particular, do you get something like `Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8081 (http)`? If the console starts up, something like `Mapping servlet: 'webServlet' to [/h2-console/*]` should show up as well.

Comment: Thank you @HalleKnast, but I have : 
**server.port=8081** on **my application.properties**

the log says: **Jetty started on port(s) 8081 (http/1.1)** 

and like you said I have 
**Mapping servlet: 'webServlet' to [/h2-console/*]**

Comment: Ok. I don't know anything about flyway, but I also don't expect it to be the problem. Do you get exceptions or warning/error logs on startup or after you enter `http://localhost:8081/h2-console`? If you can post your full log I will try to take a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have h2 dependency always on scope 'compile', scope 'runtime' etc. will cause h2-console to fault. And you to to make sure you have added a servlet mapping '/h2-console/*'

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you guys. I solved the problem because I have added a base rest configuration into application.properties and I didn't expect that /h2-console was under this path.Thank you again